# What is the difference between Azure table filter and Linq when querying the table?

Tags: c#, linq, azure, azure-table-storage

Azure Table Query support both Table Filter and Linq.

So what is the difference when using them? Like filter has better performance?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

AFAIK, there's no difference. Both of them gets translated into ODATA query when the request is sent to Azure Tables as it only understand ODATA at the REST API level.

I guess it all depends on your comfort with either of these two.